How do I turn off the 3D cursor in Blender 2.79?
When I try to select different items in this case a rig, the 3D cursor comes up and I can’t select the rig.
I am new to Blender 2.79 so don’t really now what to do. I have searched it up but got no answer.
So how do a turn off the 3D cursor in Blender 2.79

Blender versions 2.79 and prior had no ability to turn off the 3D cursor which was introduced in 2.8. This however sounds like the XY Problem turning off the cursor would not change behavior. Sounds like you want to select objects, which by default was done using right click in Blender 2.79 and previous. Any reason you are using such an old version?
